# Dialog close button is positioned wrongly on several message boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When you have <= 5 votes left in a day, there's a mini-dialog that pops up informing you of this fact. There's a button on the end of it that lets you close it early, before it automatically closes. This button is usually centered vertically in the box, but today it's broken:

[image]

The same is apparently true for a number of similar popups, such as "you can't vote for your own post":

[image]

And others, like flagging, etc.

Comment: I think it looks better now...

Comment: @JonH Nope, still getting the same thing.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant...I think the position looks actually better now than the "correct" way...

Comment: Oh. Can't say I agree, but each to their own.

Comment: It's positioned wrong for me too

Comment: Same for the "Your vote has been recorded" popup

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the current [style sheet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflowmeta/all.css) for the error / warning / info message close buttons has a typo: instead of `margin-top: 11px`, it just says `margin-top: 11` without any units, which is not valid CSS.  (Thanks to Sam for [spotting this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312299/dialog-close-button-is-positioned-wrongly-on-several-message-boxes/312340?noredirect=1#comment282960_312340)!)

Here's a quick CSS kluge to fix this issue:

```css
.message.message-error .message-close,
.message.message-warning .message-close,
.message.message-config .message-close,
.message.message-info .message-close {
     margin-top: 11px;
}
```

Of course, the proper fix is to just add the `px` units back where they belong.

---

*ps.* An easy way to test this is to type 15 spaces into the comment box below any post and press enter; the UI will let you submit the comment, but the server will strip the spaces and reject it, resulting in a "Comments must be at least 15 characters in length." error box that persists until you click it away.

Comment: It looks like they just have a bug, `.message.message-error .message-close: 11;`. I'd also recommend SE update `.message.message-error .message-text` to have more `padding-right`.

Comment: @Sam: Good catch! I just looked at the buttons in the DOM inspector, which ignored the broken rule, instead of viewing the style sheet directly. Edited.

Comment: Good catch. Will push a fix soon.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now, it will be live after our next production build.